# LogCat Android - how to get filename with the error

Tags: android, logging, filenames

I have this problem:

I start a java application as "Android application" in Eclipse Juno.
So the virtual device starts and the log messages begin to scroll in the LogCat tab.
The columns of the tab are Level, Time, PID, TID, Application, Tag, Text.

Is there a way to see the filename where an error message comes from ?
For example I get the text: "sqlite returned: error code 14, msg=cannot open file at source line 25467" and the tag is "Database".
So how could I know in which file this error has been generated ?

Thanx
A

Comment: The code is not mine, I mean it's already made so I have to debug it. The message I'm speaking about (and many others) is green and if I double click it nothing happens. Same with red messages (there's only 1 red and  it says "VM aborting" with "dalvikvm" tag).

Answer (score 1):

You can double click in the red lines and they jump to the code source which gives the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use filename as a tag while logging. E.g Log.i("YourFileName", "Your Log");

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere it usually says "caused by" and then it lists files and lines where the exception happened

Answer (score 0):

I systematically add a

```
static final String TAG = "ClassName";
```

property to all classes definitions and use  it on

```
Log.x(TAG, "Whatever");
```